# How can I use a $watch() function in angularjs for Google Map API click event?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to catch the click event that happens when you click on a marker on a google map, and then execute some code. I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
             $scope.$watch('click', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                 alert("Marker was clicked");
              });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Google maps displays the map in an iframe, and you can't capture clicks like that with an iframe. I use [NgMap](https://ngmap.github.io/) for map displays in my angularJS app, and the HTML structure ends up looking like this:

```
<ng-map class='map' style="">
   <marker id='{{locale.id}}' position="{{locale.position}}" ng-repeat="locale in locales" on-click="showInfoW(locale)"></marker>
   <info-window id="foo-iw">
     <!-- info window HTML stuff here -->
   </info-window>
 </ng-map>
```

See that `on-click` in there? That is where you can get the click and do something in your code.

My JS looks something like this:

```
    $scope.showInfoW = function(e, locale) {
        $scope.vm.locale = locale
        $scope.map.showInfoWindow('foo-iw', locale.id);
    }

    NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
        vm.map = map
        var latlng, bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i in $scope.locales) { // your marker list here
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.locales[i].position[0], $scope.locales[i].position[1]);
            bounds.extend(latlng) // your marker position, must be a LatLng instance
        }
        $timeout(function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            $scope.map.fitBounds(bounds);
            $scope.map.setZoom(14)
        }, 500)
      })
```

Without trying to explain everything, you can see that (using the wonderful NgMap package) you can capture the click on the marker.